# Initial value problem for a gradient system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, dynamical-systems

Consider about an optimization problem
$$\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}}f(x) $$
where $f$ is continuous differential in an open set $U$, and suppose $x^{\star}$ is a local minimum point.

Assume $\nabla f(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous in $U$. For any vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, can we find a curve $x(t), 0\leq t\leq \delta$, which is start at $x^{\star}$ with velocity $v$, that is parallel to the gradient of $f(x(t))$ at any point $x(t)$. In other words, can we prove the existence of solution of the system:
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq6}
  \left\{
  \begin{aligned}
   & \dot{x}(t) \ \mathop{//} \ \nabla f(x(t)) , \\
   & x(0) = x^{\star} , \\
   & \dot{x}(0) = v .
  \end{aligned}
  \right.
 \end{equation}

Comment: How should that work, the gradient at the minimum is zero. So you can only have $\dot x=\alpha(x)∇f(x)$ with a continuous factor $\alpha$ and $\dot x(0)=v$ if $v=0$.

Comment: But α(x) may be ∞ when x→x＊in your comment, and v could be nonzero. In fact, consider f(x)＝x₁²+x₂²，we can easily construct x(t)，which is a ray starts from (0, 0) with direction v, and it satisfies the above gradient system.

Comment: Any continuous function is bounded on compact sets. No infinite limits at finite points. Please do "easily construct" such a function.

Comment: In this example, if v＝(1,2)，we can let x(t)＝(t,2t), then ▽f(x(t))＝(2t,4t) which is parallel to x'(t)＝(1,2), and of course x'(0)＝v and x(0)＝(0,0)＝x*.

Comment: And you need $α(x)=1/(2\|x\|)$, which is singular at the origin. Even in the product, $x/\|x\|$ is not continuous at the origin.

Comment: Your observation is right. But this example shows that the solution to the above gradient system does exist for nonzero direction v.

Comment: Yes, if you accept that the initial point is not inside the domain of the vector field and the initial condition is only satisfied as a limit.

Comment: Not means limit, but does equal to. You may check again the above example and the constructed solution. Could you give a counterexample that the original gradient system does not admit a solution?